# Hibernate @Subselect one to many field

Tags: java, hibernate

I have something like:

```java
@Entity
public class First {

    <...>

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "first-id", nullable = false)
    private List<Second> seconds = new ArrayList<Second>();
}

@Entity
@Subselect(...)
public class FirstView {

    <...>

    private List<Second> seconds = new ArrayList<Second>();        
}
```

What should I do to have `FirstView.seconds` loaded on `session.createCriteria(FirstView.class).add(<...>).list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seconds` in a `FirstView` should be annotated in a same manner as in a `First` omitting insufficient parts. In a given case it will look so:

```java
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "first-id")
    private List<Second> seconds = new ArrayList<Second>();
```

Comment: There is incorrect behavior if `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` in Hibernate 3.5.5-Final.